# SQL Join operation error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write an SQL code in `MS Access 2010` as follows:-

```
select WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Style,
WOWPerformanceData_tbl.FY,
WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Month,
PrintPromotions.[Type of Offer],
PrintPromotions.Start,
PrintPromotions.End
from WOWPerformanceData_tbl
right join PrintPromtions
on WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Style=PrintPromotions.Style
where (WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Style=[Enter Style nr:]);
```

Upon running the code, Access returns an error in the join operation pointing to the fourth line and `selects PrintPromotions`

Any feedback will be appreciated..

Thank you.

Comment: Are you not negating the right join with your where clause as well?  You would need to add `WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Style is null` or better yet move the where clause to the join `on WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Style=PrintPromotions.Style
and (WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Style=[Enter Style nr:])`;  otherwise the unmatched records in PrintPromotions will be eliminated.  or perhaps you don't need a right join in the first place

Comment: @xQbert the comment is useful. Thank you! For my purposes I switched to left join, deleted the where clause. Where in the code would I incorporate the is null statement?

Comment: You don't need to if you switched to a left join assuming table order remained the same.. Left join says... return all records from wowPerformanceData_tbl and only those that match in PrintPromotions. the where clause is on wowPerformancedata_tbl.  Since all records are returned, a null evaluation isn't needed.  This article can help explain joins http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/  More detail in answer below.

Comment: Glad you found both answers to your question helpful! Note that you can only pick *one* as the most helpful; it appears you tried to mark both as such, but only your last choice is kept. From the deleted 'answer' I gather it was Rut the Nut that found the typo in your query, perhaps you meant to select theirs as most helpful?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - you are correct. But I am facing lots of behavior and criticism for my actions here. I may be better off getting familiarized with the posting rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fine as the where clause is an evaluation on the entire set.

```
SELECT WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Style,
WOWPerformanceData_tbl.FY,
WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Month,
PrintPromotions.[Type of Offer],
PrintPromotions.Start,
PrintPromotions.End
from WOWPerformanceData_tbl
LEFT join PrintPromtions
  on WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Style=PrintPromotions.Style
where (WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Style=[Enter Style nr:]);
```

This would exclude records from printPromotions that were not in wowPerformanceData_tbl, which negates the right join.:

```
SELECT WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Style,
WOWPerformanceData_tbl.FY,
WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Month,
PrintPromotions.[Type of Offer],
PrintPromotions.Start,
PrintPromotions.End
from WOWPerformanceData_tbl
right join PrintPromtions
on WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Style=PrintPromotions.Style
where (WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Style=[Enter Style nr:]);
```

This is how you would do it to keep all records from PrintPromotions and those that matched in wowperofrmanceData_tbl.

```
SELECT WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Style,
WOWPerformanceData_tbl.FY,
WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Month,
PrintPromotions.[Type of Offer],
PrintPromotions.Start,
PrintPromotions.End
from WOWPerformanceData_tbl
right join PrintPromtions
on WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Style=PrintPromotions.Style
AND (WOWPerformanceData_tbl.Style=[Enter Style nr:]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Should that be PrintPromotions and not PrintPromtions ?